# mejor proceso y bucle en Ruby

Tags: ruby

Necesito hacer un ciclo dentro de otro ciclo, a partir de un número total de iteraciones y cantidad de iteraciones por ciclo, se me ocurrió hacerlo en for y funciona, también lo pude hacer en while, pero sospecho que no es el mejor proceso. sobre todo porque tuve que hacer un ciclo adicional para tomar en cuenta el resto de la división.

**(UPDATE)**

este es el código:

```
puts 'KABUUM!!!'
total = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclo = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclos = total / ciclo
resto = total % ciclo
c = 0
linea = ''
for x in 1..ciclos do
linea = ''
  for y in 1..ciclo do
   c += 1
   linea << ',' if linea != ''
   linea << c.to_s 
  end
  puts linea
end
linea = ''
for n in (c + 1)..total do
   linea << ',' if linea != ''
   linea << n.to_s 
end
puts linea  if linea != ''
```

**SALIDA LINEA DE COMANDO:**
(varios resultados, dependiendo de las entradas)

```
D:\sites\ruby>ruby bucle.rb
KABUUM!!!
34
6
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16,17,18
19,20,21,22,23,24
25,26,27,28,29,30
31,32,33,34

D:\sites\ruby>ruby bucle.rb
KABUUM!!!
25
5
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25

D:\sites\ruby>ruby bucle.rb
KABUUM!!!
22
10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22

D:\sites\ruby>
```

Alguna idea de como se puede optimizar???
de antemano muchas gracias....

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo con los _inputs_ y el resultado esperado?

Comment: @Gerry Modifiqué el código para mostrar exactamente lo que necesito, despues de KABUUM el primer numero es el total de la lista, el segundo numero es el ciclo y los números que están entras las comas son las variables que necesito mandar a un parametro curl. Lo simplifiqué lo mas posible para este issue.

Comment: @Gerry ahora tengo un problema, pense que lo habia resuelto con la pregunta ,pero la solucion me devuelve solamente un consecutivo, y yo necesito generar un random de 5 digitos y no me sirve, te hago la pregunta por aqui mismo o hago otra pregunta en general?

Comment: Es mejor abrir otra pregunta, así puedes mostrar más detalle y más usuarios podrían verla (y responderla).

Comment: Gracias @gerry soy muy novato en todo esto, algun dia quiero tener un buen nivel en Ruby y poder ser freelance

Comment: Todos empezamos como novatos, sigue practicando y en poco tiempo lo lograrás! Ya contesté la otra pregunta y veo que no era tan distinta como imaginaba (me había imaginado algo más complejo, pero ya entendí exactamente a que te referías con el _random_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, creo que tu solución es demasiado elaborada; el mismo resultado puedes obtenerlo utilizando el método [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
puts 'KABUUM!!!'

total = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclo = gets.chomp.to_i

(1..total).each_slice(ciclo) do |linea|
  puts linea.join(",")
end
```

- `(1..total)` crea un rango (que es *Enumarable*).
- `each_slice` regresa un arreglo con el número de elementos indicado en el parámetro (i.e. `ciclo`) en la variable `linea`.
- `linea.join(",")` convierte el arreglo devuelto en una string, uniendo los elementos con `,`.

Te recomiendo que veas todos los métodos que utiliza el módulo `Enumerable` de *Ruby* pues ofrece una gran cantidad de formas para iterar colecciones (e.g. *rangos*, *hashes*, *arreglos*) de una forma mas idiomática (*for* generalmente es evitado en *Ruby*).